# Contextual filter on entity reference field in indexed view

Tags: 7, views, entities, search

I have two pages: jobs and offices.

My jobs page is an indexed view (with Search API) which displays jobs that have an entity reference field to the office it belongs to.

I want to put a link on my office page that links to the job page which only shows the jobs belonging to that particular office.

I've followed a few examples but none of them seem to work with my indexed view. Has somebody done something similar?

This is what I did: https://www.drupal.org/node/1841004 but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the jobs for that particular office on your job page, you might want to use a parameter. you need to pass the nid of that office to the url.

Create a link similar to this:

```
  $nid = arg(1);
<?php 
    $l = l( t('More Jobs'), 'list-of-jobs',   array('query' => array('field_office' => $nid)  ));
    echo $l; 
        ?>
```

your entity reference field is "office" right? use that field for your contextual filter. then use [Views Contextual Filter Query](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filter_query) module to get the parameter from the URL. In my example, it's field_office.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me.

The machine name of my field on the job content type is field_office. I tried jobs?field_office=10 but it still doesn't filter. I added "field_office" as parameter name in contextual filter too.

Comment: That's weird, because I do this kind of things on my previous website. I might have missed something. Try using a Content NID for the contextual filter then use the parameter of field_office, use a relationship, Entity Referenced (the field referencing each other) then relate the contextual filter. Tell me what the results is going to  be. :D